# QT several async modal dialogs

Tags: qt, asynchronous, modal-dialog

In my program there is a cycle in which there is something like that:

```
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)));
```

This function is called several times. On "reply finished" the program displays modal dialog (for example, regular QDialog). The problem is that I want dialogues to appear one after another, rather than all at once, together, as it happened now.

I tried to use

```
QList<QEventLoop *> stack;
```

One QEventLoop for every "waiting" dialog. But it seems to me that this is bad solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `QEventLoop`.

If the dialog is modal, **then it prevent all others to get input**. In this case you should send a signal when the dialog is closed. You can use `QDialog::Finished(int)` for example. The signal receiver is non other than the object which opened the dialog.

```
//slot
void showDialog(){
 if(msg.size() <= 0)
  return;
 //create dialog here
 connect(createdDialog, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(showDialog()));
}
```

And you can call this method yourself for the first message.

If the dialog is non modal, then you need to use singleshot `QTimer` to delays next dialog.
Basically each time you display a dialog, you compute the earliest time you want another dialog to be shown and you set up a timer with this time. When it is fired, you check for a message and open a dialog, and so on...

However I wonder if dialogs are the best way to show continuous input of information.

Comment: These are error dialogs, so I think that it's a good way here. I think, that your solution does not fit in my case. In my replyFinished function I have: ...some code... int result = dialogExec(); if (result) ...some code... I need to show one dialog, so the other dialogues should wait before exec is called. When first dialog is closed next one should continue from where it stopped.

Comment: To prevent all others from input isn't enough in my case.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain a bit better? I think the issue with your program is that it opens a dialog without checking that one is already displayed. I would have used something like a `QTextArea` or a `QTableWidget` where I append error messages. Like a log.

Comment: modal only means it prevents inputs for other windows. So you are misusing this word then.

Comment: Yes, it opens dialog without checking if another is opened. So I want function that opens new dialog to wait until first dialog is closed and then continue.

Comment: basic idea : `A` set a variable before exec, unset it after.`B` just enqueue each message it receive. `C` check if the queue is not empty and the variable is not set, then call `A` if it is the case. Anyway I wouldn't use modal dialogs for a continuous stream of messages.